# Multiple select in grocery crud

Tags: php, sql, grocery-crud

I have 3 tables in my db "employees", "sign", "subscription", and all of my tables has this same construct.

It is possible to view in one table all my records?

```
public function index()
{
    $this->grocery_crud->set_table('employees');
    $output=$this->grocery_crud->render();

    $this->grocery_crud->set_table('sign');
    $output2=$this->grocery_crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output2);
}
```

This generate 2 tables, but I want to put all records in one table.

Sorry for my english.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused because above your code you say "view in one table" but below you say "put in one table".  I'll assume you want to "view" from the database, not "put" into the database.

If you have access to your SQL, you can get (for viewing) records from all 3 tables in a single SQL statement by using `UNION` ...

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM EMPLOYEES
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM SIGN
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM SUBSCRIPTION
```

Note that this is 1 SQL statement (I've broken into multiple lines for readability).  The database will append the results and return all records to you in one query.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Ok your SELECT is working, but I don't know how i can this in my grocery crud..

Comment: My apologies, when I wrote my answer I did not know that "Grocery CRUD" was a framework (never heard of that one before).  This may be a case where the framework hides too much from you if you cannot alter the SQL.